# Есть ли способ динамически обновлять таблицу по мере добавления данных?

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite, gui, qtablewidget

К примеру - есть изначально выгруженные в таблицу данные из бд, появилась необходимость дополнить их, по нажатию кнопки вылазит диалоговое окно, заполняются данные и уходят в бд и одновременно в таблицу, этот способ не очень мне подходит.

Можно ли сразу после добавления данных в бд заново заполнить таблицу ? Или как-то обновить её данные ?

Пробовал так -

```
self.tableWidget.clear()
table_index = 0
self.add_table()
```

Но данные не добавляются и увеличивается кол-во последующих строк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А решил я данную ситуацию таким способом -

```
def update_table(self):
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")   
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        table_index = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(table_index)
        
        if len(records) == table_index:
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(table_index)
        elif len(records) > table_index:
            con = len(records) - table_index
            self.ui.tableWidget.clearContents()
            self.tab()
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(table_index + con)
        elif len(records) < table_index:
            con = table_index - len(records)
            self.ui.tableWidget.clearContents()
            self.tab()
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(table_index - con)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я очень рекомендую вам начать изучение
[Qt SQL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html) и
[SQL Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-programming.html)

А также посмотрите некоторые ответы как правильно работать с БД использую PyQt:
[PyQt5 и QtSql, вывод элементов БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279973) ,
[PYQt5. Вызов формы для заполнения БД, считывание данных из этой формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280335)

Comment: Обязательно опробую