# PyQt5 и QtSql, вывод элементов БД

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite, qt-designer, qtsql

В общем, суть в том, чтобы в помеченном окошке (`QTableWidget`) вывести элементы БД. 
Впервые работаю с *PyQt*, поэтому не понимаю как связать *PyQt* и *Sql*, знаю что есть `PyQt5.QtSql` библиотека для этого, но не могу разобраться.

[image: Таблица для вывода данных из БД]

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
import re


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedHeight(600)
        MainWindow.setFixedWidth(900)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(47, 150, 171)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 901, 601))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#FFFFFF\';\n"
                                 "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                 "margin: 10px;\n"
                                 "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 861, 71))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(-1)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(-1)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(-1)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(-1)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("appearance: none;\n"
                                      "border: 0;\n"
                                      "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                      "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                      "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                      "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                      "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 220, 830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(811, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#2DACEB\';\n"
                                       "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                       "margin: 10px;\n"
                                       "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись к стоматологу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить запись"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить запись"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exitfunc)

    def exitfunc(self):
        MainWindow.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.** 
   Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
2. Выбираем табличное представление `QTableView`
3. Читаем комментарии в тексте кода.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
# import re


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedHeight(600)
        MainWindow.setFixedWidth(900)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(47, 150, 171)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 901, 601))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#FFFFFF\';\n"
                                 "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                 "margin: 10px;\n"
                                 "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 861, 71))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
#
#        font.setPointSize(-1)
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(                                    #"appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(                                     #"appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(                                    #"appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(                                      #"appearance: none;\n"
                                      "border: 0;\n"
                                      "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                      "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                      "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                      "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                      "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        
#        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.frame)                # QTableView  !!!
        
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 220, 830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(811, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#2DACEB\';\n"
                                       "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                       "margin: 10px;\n"
                                       "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
#        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
#        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись к стоматологу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить запись"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить запись"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.exitfunc)
#    def exitfunc(self):
#        MainWindow.destroy()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close) 
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        
        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase. 
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются здесь. 
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')  
        
        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, которое будет использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db 
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);         
        db.setDatabaseName('book.db')                               # !!! ваша db
        
        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False. 
        db.open()
        

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(), 
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.      
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("card")                                 # !!! тавлица в db
        
        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)

    def add_row(self):
        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("name", "name")
        r.setValue("age", 30)
        r.setValue("gender", "M")
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()

# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, а не подскажите как создать и вывести дополнительное окно в котором можно будет указать данные, а затем внести их в бд, весь день пытался никак не получается, узнал что, можно с помощью textToPlain считать значение из окна ввода, затем создавал виджет в QTDisigner, но не смог "сшить" его с основной программой. После сохранения данных из окна в переменную программа вылетала без ошибок.

Comment: @FatalP я попробую вам помочь. задайте новый вопрос. приложите минимально-воспроизводимый пример. который демонстрирует проблему и понятно объясните что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.