# PYQt5. Вызов формы для заполнения БД, считывание данных из этой формы

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite, gui, qtsql

Не могу разобраться как при нажатии на кнопку добавления записи вызвать окно с тремя текстовыми полями(ФИО, Назначения, Дата), затем считать с них данные и занести в БД.

Последние два пункта более-менее ясны, с помощью `textToPlain` считать, а затем с помощью `setValue` занести в БД. Но как вызвать новое окно с формой не пойму. Пытался создать в Qt Disigner форму, однако в коде использовать её не получилось из-за того, что впервые работаю с PyQt.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedHeight(600)
        MainWindow.setFixedWidth(900)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(47, 150, 171)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 901, 601))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#FFFFFF\';\n"
                                 "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                 "margin: 10px;\n"
                                 "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 861, 71))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;\n"
            "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;\n"
            "")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.frame)

        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 220, 830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(811, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#2DACEB\';\n"
                                       "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                       "margin: 10px;\n"
                                       "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись к стоматологу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить запись"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить запись"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.update)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add_row)

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('Stomatolog.db')
        self.db.open()

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("Records")

        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

    def add_row(self):
        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue('FIO', 'Вася')
        r.setValue('NAZN', 'Удаление зуба')
        r.setValue('DATA', '12.12.2222')
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()

    def closing(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.db.close)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Диалоговое окно можно создать так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedHeight(600)
        MainWindow.setFixedWidth(900)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(47, 150, 171)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 901, 601))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#FFFFFF\';\n"
                                 "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                 "margin: 10px;\n"
                                 "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 861, 71))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(                                    #"appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(                                     #"appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(                                    #"appearance: none;\n"
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(                                      #"appearance: none;\n"
                                      "border: 0;\n"
                                      "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                      "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                      "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                      "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                      "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        
#        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.frame)                # QTableView  !!!
        
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 220, 830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(811, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#2DACEB\';\n"
                                       "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                       "margin: 10px;\n"
                                       "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись к стоматологу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить запись"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить запись"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_age = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_gender = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Name:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Age:', self.line_edit_age)
        form_layout.addRow('Gender:', self.line_edit_gender)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close) 
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        
        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase. 
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются здесь. 
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')  
        
        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, которое будет использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db 
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);         
        db.setDatabaseName('book.db')                               # !!! ваша db
        
        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False. 
        db.open()
        

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(), 
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.      
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("card")                                 # !!! тавлица в db
        
        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def add_row(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return  
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        age = inputDialog.line_edit_age.text()
        gender = inputDialog.line_edit_gender.text()
        if not name or not age or not gender:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните пожалуйста все поля.')
            return             
    
        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("name", name)
        r.setValue("age", age)
        r.setValue("gender", gender)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, очень признателен.

Comment: @FatalP пожалуйста

Comment: Здравствуйте, мне чересчур неудобно вновь просить вас о помощи, но не могли бы вы объяснить мне почему не работает удаление строки в следующей теме?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283796/Удаление-строки-из-базы-данных-pyqt5-qtablewidget

Comment: @FatalP я попробую посмотреть ваш вопрос чуть позже.