# Удаление строки из базы данных PyQt5, QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite, gui, qtsql

Не могу понять почему не работает удаление строки по её **`ID`** из БД (при выполнении запроса программа завершается с ошибкой(скрин2))?

Также ради интереса хотелось бы узнать почему после выполнения `setHeaderName` не меняются имена колонок в заголовке. 
Планируемая реализация функционала программы(скрин 1):

[image: Планируемая реализация функционала]

[image: Ошибка]

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedHeight(600)
        MainWindow.setFixedWidth(900)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(47, 150, 171)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 901, 601))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#FFFFFF\';\n"
                                 "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                 "margin: 10px;\n"
                                 "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 861, 71))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;\n"
            "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;\n"
            "")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.frame)

        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 220, 830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(811, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#2DACEB\';\n"
                                       "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                       "margin: 10px;\n"
                                       "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись к стоматологу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить запись"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить запись"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Добавление записи')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_nazn = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_data = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('ФИО:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Назначения:', self.line_edit_nazn)
        form_layout.addRow('Дата:', self.line_edit_data)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;\n"
            "")
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

class Dialog2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Удаление записи')
        self.line_edit_id = QLineEdit()
        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Номер записи для удаления:', self.line_edit_id)
        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 0;\n"
            "border-radius: 15px;\n"
            "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
            "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
            "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
            "font-size: 16px;\n"
            "")
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.remove_row)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('Stomatolog.db')
        db.open()
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("Records")
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)


    def add_row(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Вы отменили добавление записи.')
            return
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        nazn = inputDialog.line_edit_nazn.text()
        data = inputDialog.line_edit_data.text()
        if not name or not nazn or not data:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Пожалуйста, заполните все поля.')
            return

        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("FIO", name)
        r.setValue("NAZN", nazn)
        r.setValue("DATA", data)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()

    def remove_row(self):
        inputDialog2 = Dialog2()
        rez = inputDialog2.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg1 = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Вы отменили удаление записи записи.')
            return
        self.model.removeRow(row=-inputDialog2.line_edit_id.text()) #????????????????????

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Скорее всего нужно вызывать коммит, чтобы изменения были применены

Comment: Насколько я знаю removeRow не требует коммита и выполняется без него. Но на всякий случай попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: Кст, а как у вас может быть минус строка? `-inputDialog2.line_edit_id.text()`?

Comment: А как вы коммит вызывали? Как-то то так `self.model.database().commit()`?

Comment: Именно так, но мне кажется дело не в нём, программа вылетает, после указания id ряда.

Comment: Почитал про removeRows (думаю, removeRow его и дергает) и там есть нюансы, зависящие от edit strategy: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#removeRows, возможно в этих нюансах ваши проблемы

Comment: Проглядел про вылетает, тогда тем более вопрос к тому почему вы в `self.model.removeRow(row` засовываете строку `inputDialog2.line_edit_id.text()`, а не число

Comment: Я хочу реализовать удаление по id строки, который вводится пользователем в диалоговом окне, которое вызывается при нажатии на кнопку "Удаление записи".

Comment: `removeRow` принимает `int row`, поэтому вам по вашей строке нужно найти тот `row` и уже его передавать. В модели есть метод поиска: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match Или вы можете попробовать вручную перебрать модуль строка-за-строкой, но думаю лучше использовать `match`. Метод `match`, думаю, вернет список QModelIndex, можно будет взять первый элемент и у него `row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил метод удаления записи в свой ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос.

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedHeight(600)
        MainWindow.setFixedWidth(900)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(47, 150, 171)")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 901, 601))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#FFFFFF\';\n"
                                 "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                 "margin: 10px;\n"
                                 "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 861, 71))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(                                    
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(                                     
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(                                   
                                        "border: 0;\n"
                                        "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                        "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                        "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                        "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                        "font-size: 16px;\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(                                     
                                      "border: 0;\n"
                                      "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                      "background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(45, 172, 235), stop:1 rgba(72,102,175));\n"
                                      "color: #FFFFFF;\n"
                                      "padding: 8px 16px;\n"
                                      "font-size: 16px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.frame)            # QTableView  !!!
        
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 220, 830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(830, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(811, 351))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("border: 4px solid \'#2DACEB\';\n"
                                       "border-radius: 15px;\n"
                                       "margin: 10px;\n"
                                       "background: #FFFFFF")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись к стоматологу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить запись"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить запись"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_age = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_gender = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Name:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Age:', self.line_edit_age)
        form_layout.addRow('Gender:', self.line_edit_gender)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close) 
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.on_del_record)            # Удалить запись
        
        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase. 
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются здесь. 
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')  
        
        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, которое будет использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db 
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);         
        db.setDatabaseName('book.db')         # !!! ваша db
        
        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False. 
        db.open()
        

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(), 
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.      
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("card")           # !!! тавлица в db
        
        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)

    def add_row(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return  
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        age = inputDialog.line_edit_age.text()
        gender = inputDialog.line_edit_gender.text()
        if not name or not age or not gender:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните пожалуйста все поля.')
            return             
    
        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("name", name)
        r.setValue("age", age)
        r.setValue("gender", gender)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
#     Удалить запись   
    def on_del_record(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите запись для удаления.')
            return          

        name = self.model.record(row).value(1)
        age = self.model.record(row).value(2)
        gender = self.model.record(row).value(3)
        
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        inputDialog.setWindowTitle('Удалить запись ???')
        inputDialog.line_edit_name.setText(name)
        inputDialog.line_edit_age.setText(str(age))
        inputDialog.line_edit_gender.setText(gender)       
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return  

        self.model.removeRow(self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row())      # Удалить запись   !!!           
        self.model.select()                                              # Удалить запись   !!!
        
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Успех', 'Запись удалена.')
        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]